# React native scroll problem on Android with inputs which are aligned right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a problem with having right aligned inputs inside of a ScrollView. The problem is when you want to scroll with having the focus on the input it won't work. The problem only occurs on Android. When I'm using left align there's no problem.

Possible fix is setting MultiLine to true but it's not a working solution for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the code which you have problem in

Comment: Providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make it much easier to help troubleshoot your issue, since we could then run concise code containing the problem.